# How to give Xamarin.iOS StoreKit framework references or ignore the need

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I built a Xamarin.iOS binding library for Flurry Analytics. It works great, except I can't build in release mode. It says

```
Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: SKPaymentQueue. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211)
```

In the Flurry.h file I can see that it needs StoreKit

```
/*!
 *  @brief Records an Apple Store transaction.
 *  @since 7.8.0
 *
 *  This method needs to be called before a transaction is finished and finalized.
 *  @note: Needs a 'required' dependency on StoreKit for this API to function correctly.
 *
 *  @param transaction an SKPaymentTransaction.
 *  @param statusCallback a callback gettign called when the status of  ID that is associated with the event
 *
 */
+ (void) logPaymentTransaction:(nonnull SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
                statusCallback:(nullable void(^)(FlurryTransactionRecordStatus))statusCallback;
```

But I'm never going to call that method. I'm not including it in my ApiDefinition.cs.

Is there a way to build the app and let Xamarin know I really don't need StoreKit? Or, is there a way to just easily include the StoreKit.framework reference even though I'm not using it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Frameworks` property within the `LinkWith` attribute to force the inclusion of frameworks that your app does not directly reference but the 3rd-party one requires.

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("XXXX", .... , Frameworks="StoreKit")]
```

re: [LinkWithAttribute.Frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference#LinkWithAttribute)